# Configuring fault sequence based on an error message

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I'm using an enrich mediator in order to customize the reponse sent back the the client after calling the back-end service. When the enrich mediator fails processing the response, it will be sent as is to the client, which is not really suitable to my project.
I want to configure a fault sequence that must be triggered by the enrich mediator response.

I tried to use fault mediator but i'm not sure if it is the right choice.

the error message shown on the carbon console is as follow:

EnrichMediator Specified node by xpath can not found.

How can proceed please?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to process the 'enrich mediator response'. I'd use a 'filter' to see if your message is enriched correctly

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But you have ti implement a condition in the filter mediator in order to differeciate response type. in other words, i have to do a condition that evaluate the faulty rtesposne of the enrich mediator, which lead me to the same problem.